# How to to inject some class with same property in Spring yml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to config 3 thread pool parameter,So I write the vale in the config.How to inject them in spring bean.Here is my yml file config.

```
spring: 
  threadpool:
    pool1:
      corePoolSize: 1
      maxPoolSize: 10 
    pool2:
      corePoolSize: 2
      maxPoolSize: 20
    pool3:
      corePoolSize: 3
      maxPoolSize: 30
```

Here is the bean.Is that right?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.threadpool")
public class PoolConfig { 
public  class CommonPool  {
    public int getCorePoolSize() {
        return corePoolSize;
    }
    public void setCorePoolSize(int corePoolSize) {
        this.corePoolSize = corePoolSize;
    }

    public int getMaxPoolSize() {
        return maxPoolSize;
    }

    public void setMaxPoolSize(int maxPoolSize) {
        this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
    } 
    int corePoolSize;
    int maxPoolSize; 
} 
public   class Pool1 extends CommonPool     {  } 
public   class Pool2 extends CommonPool     {  } 
public   class Pool3 extends CommonPool     {  } 
}
```

In the other bean,I try to get each pool parameter like poolConfig.Pool1,but I can not do that,How to fix it?

```
 @Autowired
 PoolConfig poolConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this,

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PoolConfig() {
   private CommonPool pool1;
   private CommonPool pool2;
   private CommonPool pool3;
   // getter, setter,  ...

   public static class CommonPool() {
      private int corePoolSize;
      private int maxPoolSize;
      // getter, setter, ...
   }
}
```

I personally recommend to use list. Your yml should look like,

```
spring: 
  threadpool:
    - poolName: pool1
      corePoolSize: 1
      maxPoolSize: 10 
    - corePoolSize: 2
      poolName: pool2
      maxPoolSize: 20
    - poolName: pool3
      corePoolSize: 3
      maxPoolSize: 30
```

and your PoolConfig class should be like,

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PoolConfig() {
   private List<CommonPool> pools;
   // getter, setter,  ...

   public static class CommonPool() {
      private String poolname;
      private int corePoolSize;
      private int maxPoolSize;
      // getter, setter, ...
   }
}
```

See also the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-list